# I found where the segmentation fault occurs, but I don't know what to do now

Tags: c, simd, simd-library

Basically, I'm taking a course called parallel programming. However, I have no experience programming in C and am not too knowledgeable in computer architecture.

I know that cache is faster than memory... However, I have no idea how these concepts relate to C programming.

anyways my task is to make a fast version of matrix multiplication. From what I've googled online I should be using SIMD SSE, which is a interface that allows you to execute multiple operations at once and use loop unrolling.

However, when I try it, I keep getting a segmentaiton fault. I used printf() to find where it occurs, but I still don't understand why or what to do afterward.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
const char* dgemm_desc = "Simple blocked dgemm.";

#if !defined(BLOCK_SIZE)
#define BLOCK_SIZE 41
#endif

#define min(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
void do_block_fast (int lda, int M, int N, int K, double* A, double* B, double* C)
{
 static double a[BLOCK_SIZE*BLOCK_SIZE] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
static double temp[1] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
  __m128d vec1;
  __m128d vec2;
  __m128d vec3;
  __m128d vec4;

    // make a local aligned copy of A's block
 for( int j = 0; j < K; j++ )
        for( int i = 0; i < M; i++ )
            a[i+j*BLOCK_SIZE] = A[i+j*lda];
    /* For each row i of A */
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    /* For each column j of B */
      for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j)
        {
            /* Compute C(i,j) */
            double cij = C[i+j*lda];
            for (int k = 0; k < K; k += 2){
                printf("0");
                vec1 = _mm_load_pd(&a[i+k*BLOCK_SIZE]);
                printf("1");
                vec2 = _mm_loadu_pd (&B[k+j*lda]);
                printf("2");
                vec3 = _mm_mul_pd(vec1, vec2);
                printf("3"); 
                _mm_storeu_pd(&temp[0], vec3);

                printf("4"); // SEGMENTATION fault occurs right after 4 is printed
                cij += temp[0];
                printf("5");
            }
            printf("5");
            C[i+j*lda] = cij;
        }
}
```

The error occurs after printf("4"); However I'm unsure why. I've tried different (alligned (x))) versions of the temp[] array. I even tried replacing it with a regular variable. But the segmentation fault still happens. 
i
Here's the main routine that calls do_block_fast()

```
/* This routine performs a dgemm operation
 *  *  C := C + A * B
 *   * where A, B, and C are lda-by-lda matrices stored in column-major format. 
 *    * On exit, A and B maintain their input values. */
void square_dgemm (int lda, double* A, double* B, double* C)
{
  /* For each block-row of A */
  for (int i = 0; i < lda; i += BLOCK_SIZE)
    /* For each block-column of B */
    for (int j = 0; j < lda; j += BLOCK_SIZE)
      /* Accumulate block dgemms into block of C */
      for (int k = 0; k < lda; k += BLOCK_SIZE)
      {
        /* Correct block dimensions if block "goes off edge of" the matrix */
        int M = min (BLOCK_SIZE, lda-i);
        int N = min (BLOCK_SIZE, lda-j);
        int K = min (BLOCK_SIZE, lda-k);

        /* Perform individual block dgemm */
        if((M % BLOCK_SIZE == 0) && (N % BLOCK_SIZE == 0) && (K % BLOCK_SIZE == 0))
        {
                do_block_fast(lda, M, N, K, A + i + k*lda, B + k + j*lda, C + i + j*lda);
         }else{
                do_block(lda, M, N, K, A + i + k*lda, B + k + j*lda, C + i + j*lda);
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: <O/T> jumping into a parallel programming class with no prior experience is a bold choice. FIrst guess is `i+j*lda` can access outside the bounds of `C` where you do `double cij = C[i+j*lda];`, but I don't know how `C` is defined. If you run in a debugger you can see what `i`, `j`, and `lda` are when you crash (or print them out right before) to see if they're within bounds or not.

Comment: `static double temp[1]` only has room for one `double`, but you store 2 doubles there with `_mm_storeu_pd`.  It also doesn't need to be `static`; that just makes it harder for the compiler to optimize it away.  That doesn't really explain the segfault in the `cij += temp[0];` after it, but removing that undefined behaviour would be a good idea.  And BTW, instead of scattering debug-prints around, use a debugger to track down faults.

Comment: And BTW, you should just accumulate the Cij result for `j` and `j+1` in a single vector.  Extracting to scalar inside the inner loop is not what you want.  A horizontal sum is also not ideal (but not what you're doing here, I think).  And BTW, if you want the low element of a vector, use [`double _mm_cvtsd_f64 (__m128d a)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=1825,5214,433,720,4251,4464,4464,719,4567,4638,4637,4637,1724&text=double%2520_mm_)

Comment: You're trying to do both SIMD and parallellism at the same time without any programming experience? Wow... Talk about trying to land a plane with no engines without ever flown a plane before...

Comment: I have experience programming. I just haven’t taken operating systems yet, which usually uses C. Nor have I taken computer architecture course.

Comment: I did not review this very thoroughly, but I've noticed that at least the size of static array 'temp' is wrong. Change the second line of do_block_fast function: temp[2] instead of temp[1]